# LINQ commands took quite a long time

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, execution-time

I try some basic select statements to retrieve data from my database. Then I want to display those data on datagridview.

Problem I encountered is that the execution of the LINQ commands took quite a long time(5-10 sec, result has 1000 rows). I tried to look for an answer on this site but the questions where about much more difficult queries than my.

My code is following:

```
using (var db = new Model1())
{
     var query = from a in db.Animals
                 select a;

     dgvAnimals.DataSource = query.ToList();
}
```

Anyone can tell me why it take so long?

Comment: Are the Animal entity big with many fields? Are you quering a database over the network or locally? What version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: Do you need all 1000 rows at the same time?

Comment: There could be number of issues related to performance, Table size, number of columns, data in each row, whether db is on a network resource or local, 1000 rows **no paging** etc. Poor LINQ is least responsible.

Comment: Are you using all of the columns from `Animals`? Maybe you could improve the query by just including a few columns.

Comment: Are you _certain_ it's the query?  It could be the rendering og the datagridview.

Comment: @DStanley I guess it is the answer, Post it as answer

Comment: I wouldnt say Animal entity is big, it has 5 fields, two of which are datetimes. I am quering the database locally and i need all those 1000 rows because i want to simply display all animals in the datagridview. Version of EF is the latest released one.

Comment: @DStanley well, i am certain beacuse when i commented all the dgv stuff it took the same time

Comment: try using compiled queries

Comment: @KarthikGanesan that means what?

Comment: following link should help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38174/How-to-improve-your-LINQ-query-performance-by-X

Comment: your code should look something like this   animals = CompiledQuery.Compile((db)
        => from a in db.Animals
                 select a);

Comment: @KarthikGanesan in the given link i foun only millisecond differences. Don't think that would help me

Comment: "when i commented all the dgv stuff it took the same time" - but make sure you actually _execute_ the query by calling `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()`.  If nothing enumerates the query it won't actually execute.

Comment: yes i called ToList() on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use linq take statement to reduce size of the set

```
using (var db = new Model1())
{
 var query = db.Animals.Take(20);
}
```

If this does not improve performance, try mocking some data or pass empty set to UI and see what happens then. If taking database out of equation does not improve performance - it must be some other component that is lagging.

Comment: How does that answers the question?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel he could use it to reduce the set. and process items in batched Skip().Take()...

Comment: but OP says he has only 1000 rows, so this is no useful in this scenario

Comment: @user3568104 That would indicate that bottleneck is on the UI side try do disconnect db completely and pass empty list to DataSource

Comment: @LIUFA tried disconnecting db, and it took almost no execution time. Does that mean the problem is in my database connection or something?

Comment: @user3568104 Plug in local db that runs on your PC.

Comment: @LIUFA where/how should i plug it in?

Comment: @user3568104 Run database on your local machine (your PC), then change connection string (likely in web.config) to connect to your local database. This would eliminate network latency.